# Host-only network on Ubuntu 14.04 [VBox on W7]

Tags: 14.04, networking, virtualbox

So, I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 on VirtualBox. I'm trying to set a host-only by checking my "virtual" IP on my host's browser and access the index_html on Ubuntu, but it is not working.

Here's what I did:

Used the "ipconfg" on the cmd, here's the info:

```
IPv4..... 192.168.1.107
Netmask.. 255.255.255.0
Gateway.. 192.168.1.254
```

Then I go to the VirtualBox Host-Only Network < Properties and typed the same info excent the ip (that I will use on the /etc/network/interfaces file)

```
IPv4..... 192.168.1.111
Netmask.. 255.255.255.0
Gateway.. 192.168.1.254
```

Now I go to my Virtual Ubuntu's Settings from VirtualBox

```
sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

And change it to:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.111
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.254
```

Then I type:

```
sudo ifdown eth0 && sudo ifup eth0  // Since networking restart does not work for some reason

sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
```

From what I remembered this should allow me to connect from my host to Ubuntu, but it does not work for some reason. Did I miss something?

PS. I already upgrate and update Ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

You can not have connection this way because the [host only mode](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_hostonly) does not allow your machine to access to other machines of the network, and only your host machine can access your guest.
You need to add a second interface after enabling the [NAT mode](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_nat) to be able to access Internet.
I suggest you this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vbi69yl8CgM) (not mine) to see the difference and the need to enable the NAT mode for your guest.
The NAT interface you will add to your VM needs to be dynamic unlike the other.

```
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet dhcp
```

Comment: But if I go to my browser on my host machine and type the IP of my virtual machine I should be able to see my index_html file from apache2 from that I installed on Ubuntu, right?

Comment: @user3330190 Oh course, the host only mode will allow you that.

Comment: That's the thing, tt is not showing anything. I don't know if I missed something. Are the gateway/netmask correct, right?

Comment: @robcc In that case, please reedit your question because you ask what is missing without mentioning for which goal. On the first glance, one can understand you have connection problems with your VM.

Comment: Good point. I changed it now, hope it's more clear.